# Creating a one Column Array from Meshgrid Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working on a open source code, which should have a mesh file that is a 1D array. I create the mesh via MESHGRID in Matlab and then use FOR loop to stack the data column wise to create the file. It takes a very long time because of the FOR looping. Could anyone suggest me a better algorithm for this problem which will speed-up my process. thanks in advance

```
clear all;
clc;
close all;

th = (0:0.5:360)*pi/180;
r = 0:0.2:1;
z = 5:.01:15;
[TH,R,Z] = meshgrid(th,r,z);
[X,Y,Z1] = pol2cart(TH,R,Z);




L1 = length(X(:,1,1))
L2 = length(Y(1,:,1))
L3 = length(Z1(1,1,:))

T = 1;

for i = 1:1:L1

    for j = 1:1:L2

        for k = 1:1:L3

         M(T,1) = X(i,j,k) ;
         M(T,2) = Y(i,j,k) ;
         M(T,3) = Z1(i,j,k) ; 
         T = T+1

       end


     end

 end



  dlmwrite('hpts.in',M,'precision','%2.2f','delimiter',' ','-append');
```

Comment: as a first step preallocate `M`; additionally you can check wheter is this working for you: `M(:,1) = X(:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it not just:

```
M = [X(:), Y(:), Z1(:)]
```

Although to get technically the same result, you're counting along the third dimension first where as Matlab and the `(:)` technique are column major i.e. go along dimension 1 first so you need to reorder your dimensions so use `permute` and either `(:)` or `reshape`. With `reshape` you can neaten things up by using an anonymous function:

```
columize = @(A)reshape(permute(A, [3,2,1]), [],1,1)
M = [columize(X), columize(Y), columize(Z1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacked into `pol2cart.m` and used a customized version of `meshgrid` to achieve your desired result with this code -

```
%// Inputs
th = (0:0.5:360)*pi/180;
r = 0:0.2:1;
z = 5:.01:15;

%// Start processing
Mcol1 = cos(th)'*r;                      %//'
Mcol1 = repmat(Mcol1(:).',numel(z),1);   %//'

Mcol2 = sin(th)'*r;                      %//'
Mcol2 = repmat(Mcol2(:).',numel(z),1);   %//'

M = [Mcol1(:) Mcol2(:) repmat(z(:),numel(r)*numel(th),1)];

dlmwrite('hpts.in',M,'precision','%2.2f','delimiter',' ','-append');
```

This seems to be about **`6x`** faster than for the code you would have gotten with pre-allocating `M` on my system.

Also, you can store transpose of `th` into a variable and use it at the two places which uses those transpose values - `cos(th)'` and `sin(th)'`, so that must speed it up further.